# remove all characters between slashes in a URL in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a url for examle:

```
http://www.abc.com/ABC/ABC-Boots-in-Leather/Prod/product.aspx?iid=34487
```

i have to convert it into:

```
http://www.abc.com/product.aspx?iid=34487
```

I am using a regex expression as :

```
String u = url.replaceAll("/.*?/","");
```

But it doesn't remove the text but just removes the slashes.? How should i correct it?

Comment: I am guessing that you are trying to map your domain with you application? Am i right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x = url.indexOf('/');
int y = url.lastIndexOf('/')+1;
String u = url.substring(0, x) + url.substring(y);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me! `S = http://www.abc.com/ABC/ABC-Boots-in-Leather/Prod/product.aspx?iid=34487`

Answer (score 2):

```
 String s = "http:www.abc.com/ABC/ABC-Boots-in-Leather/Prod/product.aspx?iid=34487";
          String s1 = s.replaceAll("(/(.)*/)","/");
```

output: `http:www.abc.com/product.aspx?iid=34487`

Comment: The braces `(` and `)` are not needed.

Comment: @MariuszS I know.. but I have a habit of including the regex inside round backets

Comment: It doesn't work for me!
`S = http://www.abc.com/ABC/ABC-Boots-in-Leather/Prod/product.aspx?iid=34487`

Comment: @user2556926 What you are getting?

Comment: `S=http:/product.aspx?iid=34487` and i want `http://www.abc.com/product.aspx?iid=34487`

Answer (score 0):

**Updated** to changed question

Probably not simplest solution, but works

```
String url = "http://www.abc.com/ABC/ABC-Boots-in-Leather/Prod/product.aspx?iid=34487";
String u = "http:/" + url.replaceAll("(http://)|/.*/", "/");
```

Result:

```
http://www.abc.com/product.aspx?iid=34487
```